# Running django on GAE + Cloud SQL, with third party reusable django apps ( like South)

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm planing to run a django project on google cloud plateform (GAE, Cloud SQL). The project uses several django reusable apps (libraries) like South, django-debug-toolbar, django-compressor, etc. So, i'm wondering if there is a way to manage all these libraries on appengine? if Yes, how. 
PS: I've tried to define dependencies in the app.yaml file, but i'm getting errors:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 197, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 193, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 855, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 848, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 657, in start
    options.yaml_files)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 556, in __init__
    module_configuration = ModuleConfiguration(yaml_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 82, in __init__
    self._yaml_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 272, in _parse_configuration
    return appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo_includes.py", line 63, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
    appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo.py", line 1743, in LoadSingleAppInfo
    listener.Parse(app_info)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 226, in Parse
    self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 177, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: the library "django-appconf" is not supported
  in "jobbr/app.yaml", line 13, column 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but at least South and django-compressor would not run on GAE.

GAE is a completely different platform. Yet you have SQL access to your tables, it's just an abstraction layer over a nonrelative database. There is no filesystem access, but there are tons of other limitations. Even Django itself could not be run on GAE without patches - you have to use special version, [django-nonrel](http://django-nonrel.org/).

I would suggest to read more GAE documentation so you can decide if a particular application could be run there or not.

Comment: Django is directly supported now with googles mysql implementation, fyi. Just include it in the app.yaml. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django

Comment: @PaulCollingwood `django-compressor` still wouldn't work as it needs to [write to disk](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/blob/develop/compressor/storage.py#L73-L77)

Comment: These are good comments. I can't find anywhere that definitively discusses if Django on Google Cloud can be completely vanilla (i.e. support any plugin in the Django ecosystem).